# Optimizing pgSQL function performance

Tags: postgresql, function

I really need advice. I'm trying to use the function : pivot_subrecords_set_table_1

In the following query:

```
   SELECT rec.id AS key,
   rec.primaryurn AS urn,
   rec.mx_syscreatedby AS creared_by,
   (SELECT mf_mxdate_str_to_date (epi.mx_epizoddate)) AS date_of_creation,
   epi.mx_epizodenotes AS notes,
   epi.mx_effectscountry AS country,
   epi.mx_effectsregion AS region,
   epi.mx_effectscity AS city,
   (SELECT get_epizod_subrecords (epi.id)) AS epizod_type
   (pivot_subrecords_set_table_1 (epi.id)).idx,
   (pivot_subrecords_set_table_1 (epi.id)).upn_1 AS upn_1,   
   (pivot_subrecords_set_table_1 (epi.id)).status_1
     FROM mxt_recordheader AS rec, mt_epizod AS epi, mt_epizod_subrecord AS eps
     WHERE rec.entitytype = 'epizod'
   AND rec.logicalserverprefix = 'EA'
   AND epi.id = rec.id;
```

The function looks like this:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pivot_subrecords_set_table_1(id bigint, 
    OUT idx bigint, OUT upn_1 text, OUT status_1 text, OUT upn_2 text, OUT 
    status_2 text, OUT upn_3 text, OUT status_3 text, OUT upn_4 text, OUT 
    status_4 text, OUT upn_5 text, OUT status_5 text, OUT upn_6 text, OUT 
    status_6 text, OUT upn_7 text, OUT status_7 text, OUT upn_8 text, OUT 
    status_8 text, OUT upn_9 text, OUT status_9 text, OUT upn_10 text, OUT 
    status_10 text)
    RETURNS SETOF record
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$

   DECLARE
   key   ALIAS FOR $1;
   BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   WITH sub_upn AS (SELECT * FROM crosstab
   ('SELECT  id, mx_osobastatus, mx_osobaupn FROM mt_epizod_subrecord
   WHERE mt_epizod_subrecord.mx_syscategory = ''tableepizodinfo''
   AND mt_epizod_subrecord.id = '|| key ||' GROUP BY id, mx_osobaupn, 
   mx_osobastatus
   ORDER BY id') AS ct
   (id bigint, UPN_1 text, UPN_2 text, UPN_3 text, UPN_4 text, UPN_5 text, UPN_6 
   text, UPN_7 text, UPN_8 text ,UPN_9 text, UPN_10 text)
   ),
   sub_stat AS
   (SELECT * FROM crosstab
   ('SELECT id, mx_osobaupn, mx_osobastatus FROM mt_epizod_subrecord
   WHERE mt_epizod_subrecord.mx_syscategory = ''tableepizodinfo'' 
   AND mt_epizod_subrecord.id = '|| key ||' GROUP BY 1,2,3 ORDER BY id ')
   AS cn (id bigint, status_1 text, status_2 text, status_3 text, status_4 text, 
   status_5 text, status_6 text, status_7 text, status_8 text,
   status_9 text, status_10 text)
   )
   SELECT
   supn.id,
   supn.UPN_1,
   sust.status_1,
   supn.UPN_2,
   sust.status_2,
   supn.UPN_3,
   sust.status_3,
   supn.UPN_4,
   sust.status_4,
   supn.UPN_5,
   sust.status_5,
   supn.UPN_6,
   sust.status_6,
   supn.UPN_7,
   sust.status_7,
   supn.UPN_8,
   sust.status_8,
   supn.UPN_9,
   sust.status_9,
   supn.UPN_10,
   sust.status_10
   FROM sub_upn supn
   JOIN sub_stat sust ON supn.id = sust.id;
   END;
   $function$
```

But the performance of the function is very low.
How can I increase the performance of a function or can I rewrite the query in which it is used?

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. I'll take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use [plprofiler](https://bitbucket.org/openscg/plprofiler) to figure out what is slow in your function and optimize that.